# ruby validation error message needs changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, message

I have a model called 'dropbox', that extends 'programme'.  Programme has the following validation:

```
validates_presence_of :network_id, :name
```

and so when you try to create a dropbox, leaving these out, you (unsurprisingly) get the following vaidation message:

```
* Network can't be blank
* Name can't be blank
```

Problem is, in the context of 'dropbox', we call 'network' 'category'.  How can I change the *network can't be blank* error message to **category can't be blank**

---edit---

I've tried:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    dropbox:
      network_id: Category
```

but this has no affect.  However, this works:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    programme:
      network_id: Category
```

but will change network's name everywhere (where as I just need it to be changed for dropbox).  I believe this is because network_id is a property on programme and dropbox just extends this, but there must be a way round!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the locales for that:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    dropbox:
      network: Category
```

Stick that in config/locales/en.yml to change the displayed names of the attributes. The create some error messages:

```
errors:
  messages:
    dropbox:
      cant_be_blank: Oops!
```

Then you add a message option to the model:

```
validates_presence_of :network_id, :name, :message => I18n.t('activerecord.errors.messages.dropbox.cant_be_blank')
```

Lots more info can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Comment: from that, I'm getting: ** Network Oops! Name Oops! **  Also, won't this mean that all Programmes (not just dropbox subclasses) will get the custom error message..?

Comment: I corrected the directory typo. Basically any attribute will use the names you enter there instead of their actual names (network_id or whatever else.) Take a look at the link I posted. Hopefully that will help you sort out the details.

Comment: The nesting of activerecord::errors::messages::dropbox gives you a set of messages for the dropbox model. When you want set up some for another model use activerecord::errors::messages::othermodel. Change the Oops to whatever you want your message to be.

Comment: I think I've worked out why this isn't working.  network_id is a property on Programme, not on Dropbox.  The only way I've been able to change it is by doing:
`activerecord:
  attributes:
    programme:
      network_id: Category`, but this would obviously just change the name of network_id for all types of programme not just dropboxes.  Doing `activerecord:
  attributes:
    dropbox:
      network_id: Category` has no affect.